# MSSQL: Truncate nvarchar(max) when outputted as text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

On MSSQL when I run my query I get the following output when run as `Results To Text:`

```
Description                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Another Column
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
This is a Description                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            43289
```

But interestingly there aren't any blanks at all at the end of the string, and the length is also the correct one (without any blanks)

I want to have an output like this:

```
Description    Another Column
-------------- --------------
My description 543893
```

I've tried `rtrim`, `ltrim`, `replace`, but none is working. The datatype is `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: You mean you want the length of the string as the second column? (Im asking because "My description" isnt 20 letters long :)

Comment: @Sourcery No sorry if that was unclear, the first output is my current output and the second is the one I'd like to have. The second column is just another one to demonstrate the issue, it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: This can only be done with two passes through the data - are you sure it's needed (versus dealing with presentation at a different layer)? The issue is, without inspecting the data, the result of a `RTRIM()` might still be >4000 characters and so the type of the *column* has to still be `nvarchar(max)`. (Bearing in mind that different rows can't have *different* column widths)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've checked the `len` of the actually data and the max length is 40... It's for generating reports and copying these to some text file. Are you sure there's no way? I don't understand why it's doing this.

Comment: If the max length is 40 doesn't sound like you need the overhead of the  `max` datatype anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I say, if you really need to do this, you have to do two passes through the data:

```
create table #t (description nvarchar(max),otherColumn int)
insert into #t(description,otherColumn) values
(N'Short Desc.',21),
(N'Loooooonnnnnngggggg Description',99)

declare @maxLength int
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

select @maxLength = MAX(LEN(description)) from #t

if @maxLength <= 4000
begin
    set @sql = N'SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(' + CONVERT(nvarchar(4),@maxLength) +
               N'),description) as description'
end
else
begin
    set @sql = N'SELECT description'
end
set @sql = @sql + N',otherColumn from #t'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Result:

```
description                     otherColumn
------------------------------- -----------
Short Desc.                     21
Loooooonnnnnngggggg Description 99
```

Even if you use `RTRIM`, etc, when the system is *compiling* the query, it doesn't know the nature of the data contained in individual rows<sup>1</sup>. And so it can only assign the data type `nvarchar(max)` as the type of the resulting column.

In turn, when SSMS starts to receive the result set, it's informed that the column is an `nvarchar(max)`. At the point at which it's printing the column *headers*, it doesn't know the nature of the lengths of the results it will receive, so it just has to adopt a sensible default display width that can cope with any data it receives.

I'd normally leave such format considerations to an actual presentation layer (e.g. report builder or application), rather than fiddling around and trying to force SQL/SMS to do this sort of formatting.

<sup>1</sup>E.g. one of the rows might have the `description` containing the complete works of Shakespeare, in the original Klingon.

Comment: Wow thank you for the great answer, it's really helping me understand the issue. Since this is the only way, I'm following your advice and leave this out. Your solution works great by the way, but as you said better not to include it just for formatting/presentation matters. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select Description,len(rtrim(Description)) as count from table
```

Edit

The actual problem is you set the result mode to text. Change it to grid mode. You will get the correct result

Comment: @moritzg Read my updated reply

The actual problem is you set the result mode to text. Change it to grid mode. You will get the correct result

Comment: @Madhivanan I know it's working for grid mode, but I want the output as text! Grid mode is not an option

Comment: Why do you want in test mode? You can easily export the result

Comment: @Madhivanan Unfortunately the result of `Save Result As -> *.txt` is not the same as `Results to Text`.

Comment: @moritzg, I don't know your full requirements, and I don't know the exact viability of what I'll recommend, but there's an addon, [SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com/), it can export results from grid to file in many ways. It seems possible to customize the export format to whatever text form you need. It's **at least** free to try, not sure of usage terms.

Comment: @KtX2SkD Thanks, will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for anyone who might need it in the future (including myself with how bad my memory is).

I ran into this same problem. Here was the solution I came up with:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN LEN([Description]) >= 20
            THEN CAST((LEFT([Description], 17) + '...') AS VARCHAR(20))
        ELSE CAST([Description] AS VARCHAR(20))
        END AS [Description]
    ,[Another Column]
FROM [dbo].[YourTableName];
```

I hope you find this helpful, even though it is a bit of a long-winded way to do it.